# Pandas dataframe row removal

Tags: pandas

I am trying to repair a csv file.
Some data rows need to be removed based on a couple conditions.
Say you have the following dataframe:

-A----B-----C
000---0-----0
000---1-----0
001---0-----1
011---1-----0
001---1-----1

If two or more rows have column A in common, i want to keep the row that has column B set to 1.
The resulting dataframe should look like this:

-A----B-----C
000---1-----0
011---1-----0
001---1-----1

I've experimented with merges and drop_duplicates but cannot seem to get the result I need. It is not certain that the row with column B = 1 will be after a row with B = 0. The take_last argument of drop_duplicates seemed attractive but I don't think it applies here.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `df1 = df.loc[df.b == 1] ` give you what you want or do you expect there to be rows where you have a unique value for 'A' and 'B' would still be 0?

Comment: i also want to keep rows where values for A is unique and the value for B is 0.

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to go from df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['000', '000', '001', '011', '001', '111'],'B': [0,1,1,1,0,0]}) to df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['000', '001', '011', '111'],'B': [1,1,1,0]})

Answer (score 0):

Not straight forward, but this should work

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,0,1,11,1], 'B' : [0,1,0,1,1], 'C' : [0,0,1,0,1]})

DF.ix[DF.groupby('A').apply(lambda df: df[df.B == 1].index[0] if len(df) > 1 else df.index[0])]
    A  B  C
1   0  1  0
4   1  1  1
3  11  1  0
```

Notes:

- groupby divides DF into groups of rows with unique A values i.e. groups with A = 0 (2 rows), A=1 (2 rows) and A=11 (1 row)
- Apply then calls the function on each group and assimilates the results
- In the function (lambda) I'm looking for the index of row with value B == 1 if there is more than one row in the group, else I use the index of the default row
- The result of apply is a list of index values that represent rows with B==1 if more than one row in the group else the default row for given A
- The index values are then used to access the corresponding rows by ix operator

Comment: this works great for the example given. When using it on a actual large dataset, I get the following error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0. Any idea why?

Comment: My dataset contains 500k rows with a header. Example row '6018956795013151,1310392,1,0'

Comment: also, could you walk me through the steps of your answer? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: I should have mentioned the solution assumes B==1 exists if multiple rows exist for a given A. I guess the assumption is violated and hence your error

Answer (score 0):

Was able to weave my way around panda to get the result I want.
It's not pretty but it gets the job done

```
res = DataFrame(columns=('CARD_NO', 'STATUS'))
for i in grouped.groups:
    if len(grouped.groups[i]) > 1:
        card_no = i
        print card_no
        for a in grouped.groups[card_no]:
            status = df.iloc[a]['STATUS']
            print 'iloc:'+str(a) +'\t'+'status:'+str(status)
            if status == 1:
                print 'yes'

                row = pd.DataFrame([dict(CARD_NO=card_no, STATUS=status), ])
                res = res.append(row, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                print 'no'
    else:
        #only 1 record found
        #could be a status of 0 or 1
        #add to dataframe
        print 'UNIQUE RECORD'
       card_no = i
        print card_no
        status = df.iloc[grouped.groups[card_no][0]]['STATUS']
        print grouped.groups[card_no][0]
        #print status
        print 'iloc:'+str(grouped.groups[card_no][0]) +'\t'+'status:'+str(status)

        row = pd.DataFrame([dict(CARD_NO=card_no, STATUS=status), ])
        res = res.append(row, ignore_index=True)
print res
```